# Difference between "Force" and "Override branch if exists" in Tortoise Git

Tags: git, tortoisegit

[image: TortoiseGit override branch]

I'm using git in a small team and TortoiseGit as client. On daily basis I find my local branch some commits behind a branch, without any local changes.

My course of action is to start with remote update and follow with Switch/checkout to `<remote branch>`. In case I already have the corresponding local branch, I need to check either `Force` or `Override branch if exists` checkbox to proceed.

Question: *what is the difference between the two?*

---

Further reading: I know there are other possibilities, like `Pull`, or `Reset branch to this`. The above described procedure just happens to be my favourite for various reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Force:** It will overwrite working tree with repository version.

**Override branch if exists:** If the branch which you are creating exists, this will overwrite the changes that you've done in your local branch that branch.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

See [TortoiseGit manual](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-checkout.html) (or [Git man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)):

> Force
>
> When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree  differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes.
>
> When checking out paths from the index, do not fail upon unmerged entries; instead, unmerged entries are ignored.